# laravel too many redirects errors

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my routes file:

```
Route::get('/', 'WebController@index');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'cn'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'WebController@index');
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'ACL', 'prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('login', 'AuthController@login');
        Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    });
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'token']], function () {
        Route::get("/intentional", 'IntentionalOrderController@index');
        Route::get("/intentional/add", 'IntentionalOrderController@create');
        Route::post("/intentional/add", 'IntentionalOrderController@store');
        Route::get("/intentional/selfOrder", 'IntentionalOrderController@selfOrder');
        Route::post("/intentional/selfOrder", 'IntentionalOrderController@storeSelfOrder');
    });
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'en'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'WebController@index');
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'ACL', 'prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('login', 'AuthController@login');
        Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    });
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'token']], function () {
        Route::get("/intentional", 'IntentionalOrderController@index');
        Route::get("/intentional/add", 'IntentionalOrderController@create');
        Route::post("/intentional/add", 'IntentionalOrderController@store');
        Route::get("/intentional/selfOrder", 'IntentionalOrderController@selfOrder');
        Route::post("/intentional/selfOrder", 'IntentionalOrderController@storeSelfOrder');
    });
});
```

The problem is:

When I enter the /en or /cn url, the browser will say too many redirects; but when I enter /en/auth/login or any other url, it will work just fine.

Althought I can fix this by renaming /cn to /cn/index, but still I don't understand why this is not working.

PS:
1. My laravel version is 5.1
2. Debug environment is wamp
3. Browser is chrome

---

Update:

here is my WebController and BaseController

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class WebController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view(config('app.locale') . ".web.index", ["title" => trans('common.smart_fabric'), "active" => "0"]);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $locale = Request::segment(1);
        if ($locale) {
            switch ($locale) {
                case 'cn':
                    App::setLocale('cn');
                    break;
                case 'en':
                    App::setLocale('en');
                    break;
                default:
                    App::setLocale('cn');
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `WebController@index` function?

Comment: In WebController@index you should be passing a locale param, or something

Comment: Above is my controller.As you can see, I want to display different view according to the url.